# How can I fix the space between the navigationbar and actionbar?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have added a MasterDetailPage to my project and now the Android device has a space between the navigationbar and the actionbar.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this problem?

[image: Space between]

Comment: maybe if you share the code would be easier, probably you have padding or margin somewhere .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code, it looks like you are adding the master detail page to a navigation page:

```
new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPage())
```

The `MasterDetailPage` should be at the top level and you just wrap the Detail Pages inside of `NavigationPage`.

Comment: Oh sorry, my answer was at the time as your comment. Yes, thats what I have. I have a page before the MasterDetailPage and then I push the MasterDetailPage to the Navigationstack.

Comment: @Zero base on this description there may be a bar in your `MasterDetialPage()`'s parent. Can you show your code of your parent layout?

Comment: @MikeMa I add in the app.cs "MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TaxonomyOverviewPage());" and the code for this page is above in the post.

Comment: @JamesAlt I follow your instruction but now I get a ObjectDisposedException for the MasterDetailContainer on the android device. On iOS is it okay.